# 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable -- using `np.fromregex`

Tags: python, numpy, text-parsing

This question has many answers (see [Python Math - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320766/python-math-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable)). My question is different, because I correctly expect `np.genfromtxt(...)` to return an array (i.e `np.genfromtxt(...)` is not an in place function).

I am trying to parse and store the following into a single dimensional array:

http://pastie.org/10860707#2-3

To do so, I tried:

```
pattern = re.compile(b'[\s,]')
theta = np.fromregex("RegLogTheta", regexp = pattern, dtype = float)
```

This is the traceback (how should it be formatted?):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ahanagrawal/Documents/Java/MachL/Chap3/ExamScoreVisual2.py", line    36, in <module>
theta = np.fromregex("RegLogTheta", regexp = pattern, dtype = float)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1240, in fromregex
newdtype = np.dtype(dtype[dtype.names[0]])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

If you would like to run this, please download the text file from: http://pastie.org/10860707#2-3 and run the code above.

Comment: Please post the full traceback.

Comment: You don't even use `np.genfromtxt` in your posted code.

Comment: Please don't post data on external websites. Copy it into your question.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Actually with this setup it is easier to download that data from the external website than it would be copy-n-paste it from question.

Comment: @kindall Should be good now

Comment: Your `fromregex` call makes no sense, and the exception you're getting is [documented](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromregex.html). It's what happens when your dtype isn't valid for a structured array, which is one of the several things that make no sense about your `fromregex` call. What were you expecting it to do? How did you expect that regex to extract any data from your file?

Comment: @user2357112 I believe `np.fromregex` does the following "Construct an array from a text file, using regular expression parsing." My textfile is not suitable for parsing with just one delimiter, so I thought that a regex would do the trick. I now see, however, that `np.fromregex` actually returns part of the file matching the regex I pass in! So I really need something that returns everything but whatever matches the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file has multiple lines, with comma separation, 3 numbers perline, except the last has only 2

```
In [182]: fname='../Downloads/pastie-10860707.txt'

In [183]: np.fromregex(fname,regexp=pattern,dtype=float)
... 
np.fromregex(fname,regexp=pattern,dtype=float)

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in fromregex(file, regexp, dtype)
   1240             # Create the new array as a single data-type and then
   1241             #   re-interpret as a single-field structured array.
-> 1242             newdtype = np.dtype(dtype[dtype.names[0]])
   1243             output = np.array(seq, dtype=newdtype)
   1244             output.dtype = dtype

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Loaded with a simple 'br' read, the file looks like:

```
In [184]: txt
Out[184]: b'2.75386225e+00,1.80508078e+00,2.95729122e+00,\n-4.21413726e+00,  -3.38139076e+00,  -4.22751379e+00,\n ...      4.23010784e-01,  -1.14839331e+00,  -9.56098910e-01,\n        -1.15019836e+00,   1.13845303e-06'
```

That missing number on the last line will give `genfromtxt` problems.

Your choice of pattern is wrong.  It looks like a delimiter pattern.  But the pattern in `fromregex` docs produces groups:

```
regexp = r"(\\d+)\\s+(...)"
```

`fromregex` does

```
seq = regexp.findall(file.read())  # read whole file and group it
output = np.array(seq, dtype=dtype)  # make array from seq
```

If you want to use `fromregex` you need to come up with a pattern that produces a list of tuples that can be turned into an array directly.

================

Though looking again at the error messsage I see that the immediate problem is with the `dtype`.   `dtype=float` is not a valid dtype spec for this function.  It expects a compound dtype (structured).

The error is produced by this action, where `float` is your `dtype` parameter:

```
In [189]: np.dtype(float).names[0]
 ...
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

But it's trying to do this because the pattern has produced

```
In [194]: pattern.findall(txt)
Out[194]: 
[b',',
 b',',
 b',',
 b'\n',
 b',',
 b' ',
 b' ',
 ....]
```

not the list of tuples that it expected.

==================

I can load the file with

```
In [213]: np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(),delimiter=',',usecols=[0,1])
Out[213]: 
array([[  2.75386225e+00,   1.80508078e+00],
       [ -4.21413726e+00,  -3.38139076e+00],
       [  7.46991792e-01,  -1.08010066e+00],
        ...
       [  4.23010784e-01,  -1.14839331e+00],
       [ -1.15019836e+00,   1.13845303e-06]])
```

I'm using `usecols` to temporarily get around the problem with only 2 numbers on the last line.

If I remove the `\n` and split it on commas, I can parse the resulting text fields directly with `np.array`.

```
In [231]: txt1=txt.replace(b'\n',b'').split(b',')

In [232]: np.array(txt1,float)
Out[232]: 
array([  2.75386225e+00,   1.80508078e+00,   2.95729122e+00,
        -4.21413726e+00,  -3.38139076e+00,  -4.22751379e+00,
          ...
         4.23010784e-01,  -1.14839331e+00,  -9.56098910e-01,
        -1.15019836e+00,   1.13845303e-06])
```

This pattern includes the decimal and scientific notation:

```
In [266]: pattern=re.compile(br"(\d+\.\d+e[\+\-]\d+)")

In [267]: np.fromregex(fname,regexp=pattern,dtype=np.dtype([('f0',float)]))['f0']
Out[267]: 
array([  2.75386225e+00,   1.80508078e+00,   2.95729122e+00,
         4.21413726e+00,   3.38139076e+00,   4.22751379e+00,
      ...
         4.23010784e-01,   1.14839331e+00,   9.56098910e-01,
         1.15019836e+00,   1.13845303e-06])
```

For now I'm creating a structured array and extracting that field.  There may be a way around that.  But `fromregex` seems to favor the use of structured dtypes.

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?

Comment: It's too long to be comment!  Plus you jumped in with your question before I finished editing.  I'm still not done editing.

Comment: @hpaulj I think the following should work: `theta = np.fromregex("RegLogTheta", regexp = r"\s+,(\d+)\s+,", dtype = [(np.float128)])`. The only problem is that [(np.float128)] is not a recognized dtype, which I don't understand why.

Comment: @hpaulj Oh you edited after I commented, too. Let me check that edit first.

Comment: I generalized your pattern to handle scientific notation.