# None-type in script

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm making a calculator that imports 2 unit files and calculates which one would win, and with what numbers left (have removed the tkinter stuffs as there wasn't enough space in stack overflow to let me). I run the code, and get this:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\The Ginger Knight\Documents\Uni\Software\Python\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/The Ginger Knight/Documents/Game/Game Folder/Combat Calculator.py", line 718, in allstates
    cavef1a = efsmounta(mountefsa)[0] + efsprima(primefsa)[0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I've tried multiple things, and none of them have worked. Could someone please take a look (long code, sorry), and tell me what I've done wrong? I've looked at some of the other none returns, but I couldn't match them up to what I've done.
Cheers (Code below):

```
from glob import glob
import os
import ast
from tkinter import *

files_black = glob(os.path.join('Black', '*.txt'))
files_red = glob(os.path.join('Red', '*.txt'))
files_blue = glob(os.path.join('Blue', '*.txt'))
files_yellow = glob(os.path.join('Yellow', '*.txt'))
files_green = glob(os.path.join('Green', '*.txt'))
files_purple = glob(os.path.join('Purple', '*.txt'))

side_list = ['Black', 'Blue', 'Red', 'Purple', 'Yellow', 'Green']
combats = ['Melee', 'Ranged', 'Ram']
primsecat = ['Primary', 'Secondary', 'Ram']
primsecde = ['Primary', 'Secondary', 'Hull']

files_black_neat = []
files_red_neat = []
files_blue_neat = []
files_yellow_neat = []
files_green_neat = []
files_purple_neat = []

for file_black in files_black:
    a = file_black.split('\\')[1]
    b = a.split('.txt')[0]
    files_black_neat.append(b)

for file_red in files_red:
    a = file_red.split('\\')[1]
    b = a.split('.txt')[0]
    files_red_neat.append(b)

for file_blue in files_blue:
    a = file_blue.split('\\')[1]
    b = a.split('.txt')[0]
    files_blue_neat.append(b)

for file_yellow in files_yellow:
    a = file_yellow.split('\\')[1]
    b = a.split('.txt')[0]
    files_yellow_neat.append(b)

for file_green in files_green:
    a = file_green.split('\\')[1]
    b = a.split('.txt')[0]
    files_green_neat.append(b)

for file_purple in files_purple:
    a = file_purple.split('\\')[1]
    b = a.split('.txt')[0]
    files_purple_neat.append(b)

    def allstates():
        attackbool = list(attacker.state())
        at = []
        for i in range(len(attackbool)):
            if attackbool[i] == 1:
                at.append(side_list[i])
        combool = list(combatstyles.state())
        c = []
        for i in range(len(combool)):
            if combool[i] == 1:
                c.append(combats[i])
        blackbool = list(black.state())
        b = []
        for i in range(len(blackbool)):
            if blackbool[i] == 1:
                b.append(files_black[i])
        bluebool = list(blue.state())
        bl = []
        for i in range(len(bluebool)):
            if bluebool[i] == 1:
                bl.append(files_blue[i])
        redbool = list(red.state())
        r = []
        for i in range(len(redbool)):
            if redbool[i] == 1:
                r.append(files_red[i])
        yellowbool = list(yellow.state())
        y = []
        for i in range(len(yellowbool)):
            if yellowbool[i] == 1:
                y.append(files_yellow[i])
        purplebool = list(purple.state())
        p = []
        for i in range(len(purplebool)):
            if purplebool[i] == 1:
                p.append(files_purple[i])
        greenbool = list(green.state())
        g = []
        for i in range(len(greenbool)):
            if greenbool[i] == 1:
                g.append(files_green[i])
        atprimbool = list(at_primsec.state())
        at_ps = []
        for i in range(len(atprimbool)):
            if atprimbool[i] == 1:
                at_ps.append(primsecat[i])
        defprimbool = list(def_primsec.state())
        def_ps = []
        for i in range(len(defprimbool)):
            if defprimbool[i] == 1:
                def_ps.append(primsecde[i])

        charge_size = charge_dist.get()
        num_attack = num_attack_entry.get()
        num_defend = num_def_entry.get()


        if b != []:
            if at[0] == 'Black':
                filename = b[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1b = fin.read()
                txt1b = txt1b.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1b = txt1b.split('\n')[0]
                txt2b = ast.literal_eval(txt1b)
                healtha = txt2b[3]
                attackprima = txt2b[4]
                attackseca = txt2b[7]
                rangedat = txt2b[5]
                chargeprima = txt2b[9]
                chargeseca = txt2b[10]
                defprima = txt2b[11]
                defseca = txt2b[12]
                shipram = txt2b[2]
                mountefsa = txt2b[0]
                primefsa = txt2b[6]
                secefsa = txt2b[8]
            else:
                filename = b[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1b = fin.read()
                txt1b = txt1b.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1b = txt1b.split('\n')[0]
                txt2b = ast.literal_eval(txt1b)
                healthd = txt2b[3]
                attackprimd = txt2b[4]
                attacksecd = txt2b[7]
                chargeprimd = txt2b[9]
                chargesecd = txt2b[10]
                defprimd = txt2b[11]
                defsecd = txt2b[12]
                cover = txt2b[13]
                armour = txt2b[14]
                shiphealth = txt2b[1]
                mountefsd = txt2b[0]
                primefsd = txt2b[6]
                secefsd = txt2b[8]
        else:
            nout = 0

        if bl != []:
            if at[0] == 'Blue':
                filename = bl[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1bl1 = fin.read()
                txt1bl = txt1bl1.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1bl = txt1bl.split('\n')[0]
                txt2bl = ast.literal_eval(txt1bl)
                healtha = txt2bl[3]
                attackprima = txt2bl[4]
                attackseca = txt2bl[7]
                rangedat = txt2bl[5]
                chargeprima = txt2bl[9]
                chargeseca = txt2bl[10]
                defprima = txt2bl[11]
                defseca = txt2bl[12]
                shipram = txt2bl[2]
                mountefsa = txt2bl[0]
                primefsa = txt2bl[6]
                secefsa = txt2bl[8]
            else:
                filename = bl[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1bl = fin.read()
                txt1bl = txt1bl.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1bl = txt1bl.split('\n')[0]
                txt2bl = ast.literal_eval(txt1bl)
                healthd = txt2bl[3]
                attackprimd = txt2bl[4]
                attacksecd = txt2bl[7]
                chargeprimd = txt2bl[9]
                chargesecd = txt2bl[10]
                defprimd = txt2bl[11]
                defsecd = txt2bl[12]
                cover = txt2bl[13]
                armour = txt2bl[14]
                shiphealth = txt2bl[1]
                mountefsd = txt2bl[0]
                primefsd = txt2bl[6]
                secefsd = txt2bl[8]
        else:
            nout = 0

        if y != []:
            if at[0] == 'Yellow':
                filename = y[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1y = fin.read()
                txt1y = txt1y.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1y = txt1y.split('\n')[0]
                txt2y = ast.literal_eval(txt1y)
                healtha = txt2y[3]
                attackprima = txt2y[4]
                attackseca = txt2y[7]
                rangedat = txt2y[5]
                chargeprima = txt2y[9]
                chargeseca = txt2y[10]
                defprima = txt2y[11]
                defseca = txt2y[12]
                shipram = txt2y[2]
                mountefsa = txt2y[0]
                primefsa = txt2y[6]
                secefsa = txt2y[8]
            else:
                filename = y[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1y = fin.read()
                txt1y = txt1y.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1y = txt1y.split('\n')[0]
                txt2y = ast.literal_eval(txt1y)
                healthd = txt2y[3]
                attackprimd = txt2y[4]
                attacksecd = txt2y[7]
                chargeprimd = txt2y[9]
                chargesecd = txt2y[10]
                defprimd = txt2y[11]
                defsecd = txt2y[12]
                cover = txt2y[13]
                armour = txt2y[14]
                shiphealth = txt2y[1]
                mountefsd = txt2y[0]
                primefsd = txt2y[6]
                secefsd = txt2y[8]
        else:
            nout = 0

        if p != []:
            if at[0] == 'Purple':
                filename = p[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1p = fin.read()
                txt1p = txt1p.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1p = txt1p.split('\n')[0]
                txt2p = ast.literal_eval(txt1p)
                healtha = txt2p[3]
                attackprima = txt2p[4]
                attackseca = txt2p[7]
                rangedat = txt2p[5]
                chargeprima = txt2p[9]
                chargeseca = txt2p[10]
                defprima = txt2p[11]
                defseca = txt2p[12]
                shipram = txt2p[2]
                mountefsa = txt2p[0]
                primefsa = txt2p[6]
                secefsa = txt2p[8]
            else:
                filename = p[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1p = fin.read()
                txt1p = txt1p.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1p = txt1p.split('\n')[0]
                txt2p = ast.literal_eval(txt1p)
                healthd = txt2p[3]
                attackprimd = txt2p[4]
                attacksecd = txt2p[7]
                chargeprimd = txt2p[9]
                chargesecd = txt2p[10]
                defprimd = txt2p[11]
                defsecd = txt2p[12]
                cover = txt2p[13]
                armour = txt2p[14]
                shiphealth = txt2p[1]
                mountefsd = txt2p[0]
                primefsd = txt2p[6]
                secefsd = txt2p[8]
        else:
            nout = 0

        if g != []:
            if at[0] == 'Green':
                filename = g[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1g = fin.read()
                txt1g = txt1g.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1g = txt1g.split('\n')[0]
                txt2g = ast.literal_eval(txt1g)
                healtha = txt2g[3]
                attackprima = txt2g[4]
                attackseca = txt2g[7]
                rangedat = txt2g[5]
                chargeprima = txt2g[9]
                chargeseca = txt2g[10]
                defprima = txt2g[11]
                defseca = txt2g[12]
                shipram = txt2g[2]
                mountefsa = txt2g[0]
                primefsa = txt2g[6]
                secefsa = txt2g[8]
            else:
                filename = g[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1g = fin.read()
                txt1g = txt1g.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1g = txt1g.split('\n')[0]
                txt2g = ast.literal_eval(txt1g)
                healthd = txt2g[3]
                attackprimd = txt2g[4]
                attacksecd = txt2g[7]
                chargeprimd = txt2g[9]
                chargesecd = txt2g[10]
                defprimd = txt2g[11]
                defsecd = txt2g[12]
                cover = txt2g[13]
                armour = txt2g[14]
                shiphealth = txt2g[1]
                mountefsd = txt2g[0]
                primefsd = txt2g[6]
                secefsd = txt2g[8]
        else:
            nout = 0

        if r != []:
            if at[0] == 'Red':
                filename = r[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1r = fin.read()
                txt1r = txt1r.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1r = txt1r.split('\n')[0]
                txt2r = ast.literal_eval(txt1r)
                healtha = txt2r[3]
                attackprima = txt2r[4]
                attackseca = txt2r[7]
                rangedat = txt2r[5]
                chargeprima = txt2r[9]
                chargeseca = txt2r[10]
                defprima = txt2r[11]
                defseca = txt2r[12]
                shipram = txt2r[2]
                mountefsa = txt2r[0]
                primefsa = txt2r[6]
                secefsa = txt2r[8]
            else:
                filename = r[0]
                fin = open(filename, 'r')
                txt1r = fin.read()
                txt1r = txt1r.split('BELOW IS FOR COMBAT CODE ONLY:\n')[1]
                txt1r = txt1r.split('\n')[0]
                txt2r = ast.literal_eval(txt1r)
                healthd = txt2r[3]
                attackprimd = txt2r[4]
                attacksecd = txt2r[7]
                chargeprimd = txt2r[9]
                chargesecd = txt2r[10]
                defprimd = txt2r[11]
                defsecd = txt2r[12]
                cover = txt2r[13]
                armour = txt2r[14]
                shiphealth = txt2r[1]
                mountefsd = txt2r[0]
                primefsd = txt2r[6]
                secefsd = txt2r[8]
        else:
            nout = 0

        def efsmounta(mountefsa):
            for mountef in mountefsa:
                if mountef == '+10% vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb1 = 1.1
                    infefb1 = 1.0
                    armefb1 = 1.0
                    charefb1 = 1.0
                    return cavefb1, infefb1, armefb1, charefb1
                elif mountef == '+20 vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb1 = 1.2
                    infefb1 = 1.0
                    armefb1 = 1.0
                    charefb1 = 1.0
                    return cavefb1, infefb1, armefb1, charefb1
                elif mountefsa[0] == '+20 vs Infantry' and mountefsa[1] == '-20% vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb1 = 0.8
                    infefb1 = 1.2
                    armefb1 = 1.0
                    charefb1 = 1.0
                    return cavefb1, infefb1, armefb1, charefb1
                else:
                    cavefb1 = 1.0
                    infefb1 = 1.0
                    armefb1 = 1.0
                    charefb1 = 1.0
                    return cavefb1, infefb1, armefb1, charefb1

        def efsprima(primefsa):
            for primef in primefsa:
                if primefsa[0] == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour' and primefsa[1] == '+30% vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primef == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primef == 'Ignore 1/8 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -(1/8)
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primef == 'Ignore 1/3 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -(2/3)
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primef == '+30% vs Cavalry':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primefsa[0] == '+60% vs Mounted Units' and primefsa[1] == '1/2 Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.6
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = -0.5
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primefsa[0] == '+80% vs Mounted Units' and primefsa[1] == 'Ignore Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.8
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = -1.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                else:
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2


        def efsseca(secefsa):
            for secef in secefsa:
                if secefsa[0] == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour' and secefsa[1] == '+30% vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == 'Ignore 1/8 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -(1/8)
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == 'Ignore 1/3 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -(2/3)
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == '+30% vs Cavalry':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secefsa[0] == '+60% vs Mounted Units' and secefsa[1] == '1/2 Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.6
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = -0.5
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secefsa[0] == '+80% vs Mounted Units' and secefsa[1] == 'Ignore Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.8
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = -1
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                else:
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
            return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2


        def efsmountd(mountefsd):
            for mountef in mountefsd:
                if mountef == '+10% vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb1 = 1.1
                    infefb1 = 1
                    armefb1 = 1
                    charefb1 = 1
                    return cavefb1, infefb1, armefb1, charefb1
                elif mountef == '+20 vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb1 = 1.2
                    infefb1 = 1
                    armefb1 = 1
                    charefb1 = 1
                    return cavefb1, infefb1, armefb1, charefb1
                elif mountefsd[0] == '+20 vs Infantry' and mountefsd[1] == '-20% vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb1 = 0.8
                    infefb1 = 1.2
                    armefb1 = 1
                    charefb1 = 1
                    return cavefb1, infefb1, armefb1, charefb1
                else:
                    cavefb1 = 1
                    infefb1 = 1
                    armefb1 = 1
                    charefb1 = 1
                    return cavefb1, infefb1, armefb1, charefb1

        def efsprimd(primefsd):
            for primef in primefsd:
                if primefsd[0] == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour' and primefsd[1] == '+30% vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primef == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primef == 'Ignore 1/8 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = -(1/8)
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primef == 'Ignore 1/3 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = -(2/3)
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primef == '+30% vs Cavalry':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = 0
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primefsd[0] == '+60% vs Mounted Units' and primefsd[1] == '1/2 Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.6
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = 0
                    charefb2 = -0.5
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif primefsa[0] == '+80% vs Mounted Units' and primefsa[1] == 'Ignore Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.8
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = 0
                    charefb2 = -1
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                else:
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = 0
                    cavefb2 = 0
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2

        def efssecd(secefsd):
            for secef in secefsd:
                if secefsd[0] == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour' and secefsd[1] == '+30% vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == 'Ignore 1/8 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = -(1/8)
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == 'Ignore 1/3 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = -(2/3)
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == '+30% vs Cavalry':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = 0
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secefsd[0] == '+60% vs Mounted Units' and secefsd[1] == '1/2 Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.6
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = 0
                    charefb2 = -0.5
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secefsd[0] == '+80% vs Mounted Units' and secefsd[1] == 'Ignore Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.8
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = 0
                    charefb2 = -1
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                else:
                    infefb2 = 0
                    armefb2 = 0
                    cavefb2 = 0
                    charefb2 = 0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2

        cavef1a = efsmounta(mountefsa)[0] + efsprima(primefsa)[0]
        cavef2a = efsmounta(mountefsa)[0] + efsseca(secefsa)[0]
        infef1a = efsmounta(mountefsa)[1] + efsprima(primefsa)[1]
        infef2a = efsmounta(mountefsa)[1] + efsseca(secefsa)[1]
        armef1a = efsmounta(mountefsa)[2] + efsprima(primefsa)[2]
        armef2a = efsmounta(mountefsa)[2] + efsseca(secefsa)[2]
        charef1a = efsmounta(mountefsa)[3] + efsprima(primefsa)[3]
        charef2a = efsmounta(mountefsa)[3] + efsseca(secefsa)[3]

        cavef1d = efsmountd(mountefsd)[0] + efsprimd(primefsd)[0]
        cavef2d = efsmountd(mountefsd)[0] + efssecd(secefsd)[0]
        infef1d = efsmountd(mountefsd)[1] + efsprimd(primefsd)[1]
        infef2d = efsmountd(mountefsd)[1] + efssecd(secefsd)[1]
        armef1d = efsmountd(mountefsd)[2] + efsprimd(primefsd)[2]
        armef2d = efsmountd(mountefsd)[2] + efssecd(secefsd)[2]
        charef1d = efsmountd(mountefsd)[3] + efsprimd(primefsd)[3]
        charef2d = efsmountd(mountefsd)[3] + efssecd(secefsd)[3]

        print(attackprima, attackprimd)

    Button(root, text='Fight!', command=allstates).pack(side=RIGHT)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Math - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320766/python-math-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so I found the problem myself. What I actually did above was that if either mountefsa/mountefsd/primefsa/primefsd/secefsa/secefsd were equal to [] (ie, there were none), the definitions afterwards searched this empty list and assigned values from that empty list, meaning that when I referenced those values, I returned a None Type. Here is an example definition done correctly:

```
    def efssecd(secefsd):
        if secefsd != []:
            for i in range(len(secefsd)):
                secef = secefsd[i]
                print(secef)
                if secefsd[0] == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour' and secefsd[1] == '+30% vs Mounted Units':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    print(cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2)
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == 'Ignore 1/4 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -0.25
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == 'Ignore 1/8 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -(1/8)
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == 'Ignore 1/3 Armour':
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = -(2/3)
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secef == '+30% vs Cavalry':
                    cavefb2 = 0.3
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secefsd[0] == '+60% vs Mounted Units' and secefsd[1] == '1/2 Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.6
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = -0.5
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                elif secefsd[0] == '+80% vs Mounted Units' and secefsd[1] == 'Ignore Enemy Charge Bonus':
                    cavefb2 = 0.8
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = -1
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
                else:
                    infefb2 = 0.0
                    armefb2 = 0.0
                    cavefb2 = 0.0
                    charefb2 = 0.0
                    print(cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2)
                    return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
        else:
            infefb2 = 0.0
            armefb2 = 0.0
            cavefb2 = 0.0
            charefb2 = 0.0
            print(cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2)
            return cavefb2, infefb2, armefb2, charefb2
```