# what is meaning of error 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

I am working on face recognition project , in which I train the model.  prediction I load images and want to calculate distanse betwwen 2 images. while predection i am getting below error:

```
             TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
       <ipython-input-21-0b1f36824e17> in <module>()
  8   if(cropped_img == type(None)):
  9     cropped_img = np.zeros(shape = (224, 224))
  ---> 10   img = (load_image(cropped_img) / 255.).astype(np.float32)
 11   img = cv2.resize(img, dsize = (224,224))
 12   embedding_vector = vgg_face_descriptor.predict(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0))[0]

 <ipython-input-9-6d96fb74d85b> in load_image(path)
  4     # OpenCV loads images with color channels
  5     # in BGR order. So we need to reverse them
  ----> 6     return img[...,::-1]

 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

code is below

```
      NoneType = type(None)


embedding =[]
for i, m in enumerate(metadata):
   cropped_img = m.image_path()
   print(i)
  if(cropped_img == type(None)):
     cropped_img = np.zeros(shape = (224, 224))
  img = (load_image(cropped_img) / 255.).astype(np.float32)
  img = cv2.resize(img, dsize = (224,224))
  embedding_vector = vgg_face_descriptor.predict(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0))[0]

  embedding.append(embedding_vector)
```

Load image code is as below:

```
       def load_image(path):
         img = cv2.imread(path, 1)
         # OpenCV loads images with color channels
         # in BGR order. So we need to reverse them
         return img[...,::-1]
```

As I am new to python I can not understand what this error means

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Math - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320766/python-math-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable)

Comment: no this is not exectly

Comment: What are `NoneType = type(None)` and `cropped_img == type(None)` for??

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> None == type(None)
False
```

So, if `cropped_img` is None, your comparison `if(cropped_img == type(None)):` will be `False`. And thus, `cropped_img = np.zeros(shape = (224, 224))` will never be executed, so `cropped_img` *will remain `None`* and will be passed on to `load_image`, which, as the error message shows, doesn't work with `None`.

You should check like this:

```
if cropped_img is None:
    cropped_img = np.zeros(shape = (224, 224))
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. but still  getting same error

Comment: @RajanikantShukla, what's the output of `print(cropped_img)` _right before_ you call `load_image`?

Comment: 5948, if is not getting executed as i add print statement in if. print(cropped_img) --> no output

Answer (score -1):

below code will resolve the problem as imread gives None

```
     def load_image(path):
       img = cv2.imread(path, 1)
        if type(img) == type(None):
           img = np.zeros(shape = (224, 224))
     # OpenCV loads images with color channels
     # in BGR order. So we need to reverse them
       return img[...,::-1]
```

Comment: `if type(img) == type(None):` -> `if img is None:` -> maybe even `if not img:`.