# What is wrong with my Covid Tracker Telegram Bot?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, tracker

I have a simple Telegram Bot in python which worked normal, I have run it today and I got an error for a specific country which says the following;

```
return self.callback(update, context)
  File "main.py", line 21, in stats
    data['confirmed'],
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is my code;

```
from telegram import ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, ConversationHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from covid19 import Covid19

buttons = ReplyKeyboardMarkup([['Statistics'], ['World']], resize_keyboard=True)
covid = Covid19()
TOKEN = '**********'

def start(update, context):
    update.message.reply_html(
        '<b>Greetings, {}</b>\n \n some text'.format(update.message.from_user.first_name), reply_markup=buttons)
    return 1

def stats(update, context):
    data = covid.getByCountryCode('UA')
    update.message.reply_html(
        ' <b>In Ukraine</b>\n \n<b>Infected:</b> {}\n<b>Recovered:</b> {}\n<b>Dead:</b> {}'.
            format(
            data['confirmed'],
            data['recovered'],
            data['deaths']), reply_markup=buttons)

def world(update, context):
    data = covid.getLatest()
    update.message.reply_html(
        ' <b>World</b>\n \n<b>Infected:</b> {}\n<b>Recovered:</b> {}\n<b>Dead:</b> {}'.format(
            "{:,}".format(data['confirmed']),
            "{:,}".format(data['recovered']),
            "{:,}".format(data['deaths'])
        ), reply_markup=buttons)

updater = Updater(TOKEN, use_context=True)
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points = [CommandHandler('start', start)],
    states={
        1: [MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(Statistics)$'), stats),
            MessageHandler(Filters.regex('^(World)$'), world),
            ]
    },
    fallbacks=[MessageHandler(Filters.text, start)]
)

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

After `/start` it brings two buttons - Statistics and World, when I click or type World it works normally when I click on Statistics, it brings that error I mentioned above.

**So what is wrong with my code, it worked a couple of days ago, and now what am I doing wrong?**

My question is different than this one *[Python Math - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320766/python-math-typeerror-nonetype-object-is-not-subscriptable)*. Mine is Telegram Tracker Bot which worked a day before and now it stopped working, the reason is this part;

```
def stats(update, context):
    data = covid.getByCountryCode('UA')
    update.message.reply_html(
        ' <b>In Ukraine</b>\n \n<b>Infected:</b> {}\n<b>Recovered:</b> {}\n<b>Dead:</b> {}'.
            format(
            data['confirmed'],
            data['recovered'],
            data['deaths']), reply_markup=buttons)
```

What is wrong here, the error could be the same but this is written in telegram and COVID modules not only math.
I will appreciate it if someone corrects my code.

Answer (score 0):

What this message is saying is that your variable `data` has no value (i.e. it has the value of `None`). Therefore, you cannot ask Python what is `data['confirmed']`.

Since you are getting the value of `data` from `covid.getByCountryCode('UA')`, it would make sense to check why this call is returning `None`. Perhaps read the documentation or look at its source code. I'd venture to guess that it's making a call to some online webservice which is either down or not working as expected.